ZMK with hold-trigger-key-positions and pressing 2 mod keys on the same side
I am tyrying to configure HomeRow mods for ZMK Keyboard in a way, that the mod is only triggered by keys on the other side of the keyboard:
 behaviors {
            lhm: left_homerow_mods {
                compatible = "zmk,behavior-hold-tap";
                #binding-cells = <2>;
                tapping-term-ms = <200>;    // <---[[moderate duration]]
                quick-tap-ms = <0>;
                flavor = "balanced";
                bindings = <&kp>, <&kp>;
                hold-trigger-key-positions = <6 7 8 9 10 11 18 19 20 21 22 23 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41>;
            };
            rhm: right_homerow_mods {
                compatible = "zmk,behavior-hold-tap";
                #binding-cells = <2>;
                tapping-term-ms = <200>;    // <---[[moderate duration]]
                quick-tap-ms = <0>;
                flavor = "balanced";
                bindings = <&kp>, <&kp>;
                hold-trigger-key-positions = <0 1 2 3 4  5  12 13 14 15 16 17 24 25 26 27 28 29 36 37 38 39 40 41>;
            };
};

Example in the config:
&lhm LWIN S &lhm LALT D &lhm LCTRL F

This works good, except for if I want to press 2 mods at the time. In these cases I want to press the two mods on one hand, and the other key on the other hand (same way as with one mod).
But it does not work. If I press 2 mod keys on one side, only one is registered as a mode and the other as a tap.
Anyone has a good setup, that on one hand uses the "hold-trigger-key-positions" but also allows pressing 2 mod keys on one hand?
Thanks

You need to enable the hold-trigger-on-release setting. If you look up Urob's homerow mods, he goes into depth about the setup you're looking for.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
